# Google Analytics - Tracking User from other web sites

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have a Silverlight LOB application. This application can be launched from external web sites. We want to track where the user is coming from. Assume our silverlight web site is "A", and there are two external web sites "C" & "D". It's possible that users launch our web site from "C" or "D". We want to know:

1. How many users came from "C"?
2. How many users came from "D"?
3. What are the various actions performed by users who came from external web site "C" and web site "D"

Is it feasible to support the above requirement? Does google analytics support the above scenario? If so, how we should approach this? Any pointers or examples will be very helpful

Thanks

Rasheed

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics has built in referral urls support.
If you want to go a little more fancy, create different profiles with the right filters in order to extract a tad more info. [This](http://jaredhuber.com/web-analytics/tracking-full-referral-urls-in-google-analytics/) may be interesting read for you.
I don't know if you will be able to do a lot about 3, since I have no experience tracking silverlight events and flows, but you may want to take a look at [goals](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55580).